# Accessing a NAS from a Raspberry Pi - working but looking for additional information

Tags: raspberry-pi, fstab, nas

So after quite some time messing around I have managed to access my assorted NASes on boot, but there are a zillion contradictory answers out there (I couldn't find one that actually worked as I wanted it). So here's my answer that works for me, however my question (which is why I'm here after all) is what extra options would be good to add to the `fstab` line, as you can see I've gone with a pretty minimal set:

In the current (Aug 2023) Raspberry Pi 64-bit OS on a Pi4 (I would expect it to work on older Pi models, older OS versions and the 32-bit OS):

In the main top-left menu choose `Preferences`->`Raspberry Pi Configuration`, then in the `System` tab enable `Network on Boot`.

Make file `/etc/.cifsauth` containing two lines (editing the right side of the = signs to suit):

```
username=nas-logon-name

password=password-for-nas-logon-name
```

Then in a shell:

```
cd /etc

sudo chmod 600 .cifsauiths

sudo chown root .cifsauiths

sudo chgrp root .cifsauiths
```

Edit `/etc/fstab` and add to the end as many entries like this one as you want shares mapped (with server and logon names adjusted to suit, you can add lines starting with a hash sign around them for comments) - NOTE this is one line that was wrapped over two in this post, there is a space after cifs, except someone has kindly edited it to fix this now:

```
#[NAS]

//192.168.1.150/files /home/your-pi-user-name/server1 cifs credentials=/etc/.cifsauth,iocharset=utf8 0 0

#
```

Here there is a NAS with IP address (note it will need to be a static IP address): 192.168.1.150

We want access to a share on the NAS called: files

We've made a destination directory: `server1` in the local directory `/home/your-user-name` (e.g. /home/fred if your pi logon name is fred), either in the file manager or use the md command in a shell.

After this you can test to see if it works by typing (in a shell):

```
sudo mount -a
```

If you get an error message type:

```
dmesg
```

in a shell to see what it says, the errors should be at the end of the list (so ignore stuff that went off the top of the sceen).

Technical note:  `sec=ntlm` won't work in the comma-separated options for this OS.